# MYSQL union order in first statement

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have this query:

```
(SELECT * FROM items WHERE duration = 5 ORDER BY date DESC) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM items WHERE duration = 10)
```

The problem is the "ORDER BY" in the first query is not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: The ORDER BY makes no sense, since the UNION will re-order the rows anyway.

Comment: How do I achieve that the first query should be ordered by it's date? @jarlh

Comment: Can't you have the ORDER BY at the end, for the whole UNION?

Comment: I tried that but it also orders the items with duration of 10. I only want to order the items with duration of 5 @jarlh

Comment: Select 0 as my_order... UNION SELECT 1...

Comment: REgarding the second half of your query. Please note that there isn't a way in SQL to say don't order by anything (ie impose disorder). The best you can do is ORDER BY RAND() which is extremely slow or large resultsets

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result! (Include duplicates in the sample data, if allowed.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 select * from (
    SELECT * FROM items WHERE duration = 5
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM items WHERE duration = 10
    ) odrer by date DESC
```

Comment: This orders the items with duration of 10 as well, I only want to order items with duration of 5.

Answer (score 0):

When you use **UNION** OR **UNION ALL** order by not allowed in each select statement. You have to apply **order by in outer select statement**.

Answer (score 0):

Order the `UNION` result by duration first, then date desc.

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT * FROM items WHERE duration = 5
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM items WHERE duration = 10
)
order by duration, date DESC
```

However, there's no need for a `UNION` (see e4c5's answer).

Comment: @sagi, I know. Kind of unclear which order OP wants. You can change to `order by duration, case when duration = 5 then date end DESC` but the duration 10 order is still decided by the dbms.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you from the comments, you want something like this?

```
SELECT s.* FROM (
    SELECT i.*,1 as ord_col FROM items i WHERE duration = 5 
    UNION 
    SELECT it.*,2 FROM items it WHERE duration = 10) s
ORDER BY CASE WHEN s.ord_col = 5 THEN s.date 
                                 ELSE '1000-01-01'
         END DESC
```

Although this query is inefficient , you can do it with one select :

```
SELECT i.* FROM items i WHERE i.duration IN(5,10)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN s.ord_col = 5 THEN s.date 
                                 ELSE '1000-01-01'
         END DESC
```

If its not dynamic, and `5` will be ordered before `10` and these are constant values , you can simply add the `duration` column to the query , `ORDER BY duration,date` although this will also order the second query be date, just after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't even need to UNION at all and you can refactor your query this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE duration IN (5, 10)
ORDER BY CASE
        WHEN duration = 5 THEN 1
        WHEN duration = 10 THEN 2
        ELSE NULL
    END
    , CASE
        WHEN duration = 5 THEN [date]
        ELSE NULL
    END DESC;
```

This query will sort based on your duration first (the ones with 5 will come first, with 10 second) and then as a second order option it will sort ones with duration = 5 by date in descending order.

Of course this could be more elegant, but meets OPs A/C and does the job.